# How can I disable a button when you hover over it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, disable

I need to know how can I disable a button when I hover over it, and then enable it when I'm not.

I've tried javascript, to disable it when the mouse coordinates were just so, but it didn't work.

Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>This is a button</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

    <button type="button">Press Me</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is for a joke, but I want it done quickly.

Thanks,
*Enlighten Me*

PS: I'm new to StackOverflow, so please give any pointers to posts and such.

Comment: *'This is for a joke, but I want it done quickly.'* SO is not a coding service and certainly not one that adheres to deadlines. Visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>This is a button</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="hbtn">Press Me</button>

</body>
<script>
document.getElementById('hbtn').addEventListener('mouseenter',(event)=>{
event.target.disabled=true;
});
</script>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is what did it! Tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Setup enter/leave event listeners on your button...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

Answer (score 0):

```css
#joke-btn:hover{
display:none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>This is a button</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

    <button id="joke-btn"type="button">Press Me</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you could add event listeners for the `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` DOM events and change the `disabled` property value of the `button` HTML element.

For example, in your case, a simple code solution (not the only possible one), would be something like:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  button.disabled = true;
});

button.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  button.disabled = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest option here is to just do it with css. However this doesn't actually disable the button, just the mouse click event, so you can still click the button when it is selected by using the return key:

Assign a class to your button (you can call it anything you want):

`<button class="myButton" type="button">Press Me</button>`

And in your CSS file disable mouse clicks:

```
.myButton:hover {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```